# Java Turtle Graphics Animation Basic

Tags: java, turtle-graphics

This is a program to create a fractal by moving a turtle around the screen. Why won't the turtle in my program move? Any help would be appreciate! I am pretty sure it is an easy fix but I cannot find it.

Thanks

```
  /**
  * This program is to create a fractal
  */

import java.awt.*;
class FractalEngine
{
  World world = new World(700,700); 
  Turtle turt = new Turtle(1,1,world);

public void drawFractal(String rule)
{
    turt.penUp();
    turt.moveTo(350,350);

    int lengthofRule = rule.length();

    int start = 0;
    int fin = 1;
    String tinyChar;

    for(int a = 0; a <= lengthofRule; a++)
    {
        if(start == 9)
            tinyChar = rule.substring(start);
        else 
            tinyChar = rule.substring(start,fin);

        if(tinyChar == "F")
            turt.forward(25);
        else if(tinyChar == "-")
            turt.turnLeft();
        else if(tinyChar == "+")
            turt.turnRight();
        else
            break;
        start++;
        fin++;

            System.out.println(tinyChar);
        }
    }
}
public class FractalEngineTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   FractalEngine fEng = new FractalEngine();



  String rule = "F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F";
  //String rule = "F-F+F+F-F";

   fEng.drawFractal(rule);
   //String rule = "F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F";
   //String rule = "F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code has nothing to do with turtles -- it's all about characters and strings.

This doesn't work:

```
String tinyChar = rule.substring(start, fin);

if (tinyChar == "F")
```

You're mixing `String` and `char` logic.  You either need to do:

```
String tinyChar = rule.substring(start, fin);

if (tinyChar.equals("F"))  # use a method to do the String comparison
```

Or do:

```
char tinyChar = rule.charAt(start);

if (tinyChar == 'F')  // notice the change in quotes
```

Below's my rework of your code to address this and other issues.  I'm using a different turtle package, and have simplified things, so it won't work for you directly without some modification:

```
import java.awt.*;

class FractalEngine
{
    Turtle turt = new Turtle();

    public void drawFractal(String rule)
    {
        int lengthofRule = rule.length();

        for (int position = 0; position < lengthofRule; position++)
        {
            char tinyChar = rule.charAt(position);

            if (tinyChar == 'F')
                turt.forward(25);
            else if (tinyChar == '-')
                turt.left(90);
            else if (tinyChar == '+')
                turt.right(90);
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FractalEngine fEng = new FractalEngine();

        String rule = "F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F";

        fEng.drawFractal(rule);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

When asking a question like this, make sure to indicate where your turtle graphics library came from as there are several and they're not all the same.